# How to send emails with attachments using CakePHP 1.3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am working over to send email with attachments.
I am using php default configurations to send email but using CakePHP framework.

```
$fromEmail = $from_name." <".$from_email.">";
$this->Email->from = $fromEmail;
$this->Email->to = trim($email);
$this->Email->subject = $subjects[$this->params['action']];
$this->Email->sendAs = 'text';
$this->Email->template = $this->params['action'];
print_r($attachments); exit; // Gave me an empty Array ( )
$this->Email->attachments = $attachments;

$attachments = array( );
            if ( ! empty($this->data['Submit']['files'])) {
                $attach_files = $this->Document->DocumentDocument->find('all', array(
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'MailDocument.Mail_id' => $this->data['Submit']['prop_id'],
                        'MailDocument.id' => $this->data['Submit']['files'],
                    ),
                ));
                $attachments = Set::combine($attach_files, '/PropertyDocument/file', '/PropertyDocument/file_path');
            }
```

I understand we have to define file path in cakePHP.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set an array containing the paths to the files to attach to the attachments property of the component.

```
$this->Email->attachments = array(
    TMP . 'att.doc',
    'att2.doc' => TMP . 'some-name'
);
```

The first file `att.doc` will be attached with the same filename. For the second file we specify an alias `att2.doc` will be be used for attaching instead of its actual filename `some-name`.